# Python - decorator manipulating attributes of target functions

Tags: python, python-decorators

My goal is to come up with a decorator that would accept functions with arbitrary number of params and change the target function's attributes. One example, I need an attribute in the target function which would contain execution length in seconds.
I have tried to utilize functool's `wraps` method to preserve the attributes, but with no success. It only seems to preserve the initial attributes like `__doc__` and `__name__`, but I am not able to assign new value to non-existant attribute. 
I know that I could assign the duration attribute to `wrapper` before returning it, intead of `func`. But this is suitable only for those cases when we do not have to count for what happens inside the func, like in my case. So, here's my code:

```
import time
from functools import wraps

def my_dec(param):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            start = time.time()
            rs = func(*args, **kwargs)
            func.duration = time.time() - start
            return rs
        wrapper.a = 'a'
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@my_dec('Dec param')
def target_func(x):
    return x.upper()
target_func('test value')
print(target_func.duration)
```

Comment: Does `setattr` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning to `wrapper.duration` works...

```py
import time
from functools import wraps

def my_dec(param):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            start = time.time()
            rs = func(*args, **kwargs)
            wrapper.duration = time.time() - start
            return rs
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@my_dec('Dec param')
def target_func(x):
    return x.upper()
target_func('test value')
print(target_func.duration)
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even try that. Strange syntax. Function can reference itself right in its definition? Are you sure there are no hidden possible issues in that syntax?

Comment: I was a bit surprised myself. If you want to avoid it, you can instead use a mutable container (list, dict or object); that would avoid the reference to the function within its own definition.

Comment: I think this is because Python preserves context in case of inner functions invoking

Comment: Sure, but I was under the impression that it explicitly goes and looks for the variables that are in the surrounding scopes; that could go either way with a function that's not yet fully defined.

Answer (score -1):

Alternative answer, if you want to avoid referencing the `wrapper` function within its own definition:

```py
import time
from functools import wraps

def my_dec(param):
    def decorator(func):
        durations = []
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            start = time.time()
            rs = func(*args, **kwargs)
            durations.append(time.time() - start)
            return rs
        wrapper.durations = durations
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@my_dec('Dec param')
def target_func(x):
    return x.upper()
target_func('test value')
print(target_func.durations)
```